# Spark yarn-client mode behind a load balancer that drops inactive TCP connections

Tags: apache-spark, tcp, hadoop-yarn, rpc

I am running Spark on YARN in client mode. The driver is separated from the ApplicationMaster by a load balancer that kills inactive TCP connections after 5 minutes. This kills even active YARN jobs after 5 minutes.

This is because the [ApplicationMaster opens an RPC connection to the driver and sends the RegisterClusterManager message](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ced8e0e66226636a4bfbd58ba05f2c7f7f252d1a/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala). Following that, it only sends messages across this connection if the number of executors increases or decreases. This might not happen every five minutes. Five minutes afte the last RPC call, the load balancer kills the RPC connection due to inactivity, and the onDisconnected method is called on the RPC connection, killing the YARN job.

This is a corporate environment, and I do not have the possibility of changing the load balancer behavior regarding dropping inactive TCP sessions. I can live with YARN jobs timeouting after they are inactive for 5 minutes, but running jobs should not terminate.

I suspect the correct way would be to use [OS-level TCP keepalive for the connections](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/20512). However, the version of Spark I am using does not offer this feature yet.

Is there any way to solve this without rolling my own version of Spark that manually implements a keepalive or heartbeat mechanism in that RPC session?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this problem by routing traffic past the load balancer.